# store images in Sqlite from urls

Tags: android, mysql, sqlite

i am trying to insect data into an sqlite database and they are all names, messages and images gotten from mysql database . the problem is how to insect images using Blob.. the images are gotten from a urls. i want to put it in the sqite table.... i know they say is better to save it on the sdcard and put the location in the sqlite table.... but the only problem is that the user would be able to delete some images or rename them which i dont want.

ths is my sqlite database class

```
public class DBTool extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private Context appContext;
     static final String firstname="firstname";
     static final String lastname="lastname";
     
    public DBTool(Context applicationContext){
        
        super(applicationContext, "friend.db", null, 1);
        this.appContext = applicationContext;

    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
                
                String query = "CREATE TABLE friends ( contactId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT, " +
                        "message TEXT, image BLOB)";
                database.execSQL(query);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase database, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        
        String query = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS friends";
        
        database.execSQL(query);
        onCreate(database);
        
    }
    
    public void insertContact(HashMap<String, String> queryValues){
        
        SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
        
    
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        
        values.put("name", queryValues.get("name"));
        values.put("message", queryValues.get("message"));
        values.put("image", queryValues.get("image"));
        
        database.insert("friends", null, values);
        database.close();
        
    }
    
    public int updateContact(HashMap<String, String> queryValues){
        
        SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
        
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        values.put("name", queryValues.get("name"));
        values.put("message", queryValues.get("message"));
        values.put("image", queryValues.get("image"));
        
        
        return database.update("friends", values, 
                "contactId" + " = ?", new String[] {queryValues.get("contactId") });
        
    }
    
    public void deleteContact(){
        
        SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
        
        String deleteQuery = "DELETE FROM friends ";
        
        database.execSQL(deleteQuery);
        
    }
    
    public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> getAllContacts(){
        
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactArrayList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    
    
         String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM friends ";
        SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
        
        Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        

        if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
            
            do{
                
                HashMap<String, String> contactMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
                
                contactMap.put("name", cursor.getString(0));
                contactMap.put("message", cursor.getString(1));
                contactMap.put("image", cursor.getString(2));
                
                
                contactArrayList.add(contactMap);
                
            } while(cursor.moveToNext());
            
        }
        return contactArrayList;
        
    }
    
    public HashMap<String, String> getContactInfo(String id){
        
        HashMap<String, String> contactMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
        
        SQLiteDatabase database = this.getReadableDatabase();
        
        String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM friends WHERE contactId='" + id + "'";
        
        Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        
        if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
            
            do{
                
                contactMap.put("name", cursor.getString(0));
                contactMap.put("message", cursor.getString(1));
                contactMap.put("image", cursor.getString(2));
                
            } while(cursor.moveToNext());
            
        }
        
        return contactMap;
        
    }
    
}
```

this is my class to get the data and insect

```
public class Chat extends SherlockListFragment {
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    private static final String TAG_POSTS = "posts";
    public static final String TAG_ID = "id";
    public static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
    public static final String TAG_pic = "pic";
    public static final String TAG_MESSAGE = "message";
    public static final String TAG_CATEGORIES_LOGO = "categories_logo";
    DBTool dbTool = new DBTool(getActivity());
    /*
  user details
    private static final String NAME = "name";
    private static final String AGE = "age";
    private static final String STATUS = "status";
    private static final String PIC = "pic";
    private static final String SEX = "sex"; String friendname,status;

    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";*/
        //user
    private static final String URL_CATEGORY = "http://10.0.2.2/ochat/selectchat.php";

        private ListView lv;
        SharedPreferences sp ;
        Bundle bon = new Bundle();

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.friends, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }
     @Override 
        public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
            super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);  
        
            new LoadComments().execute(); 
 }
     
       class LoadComments extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>> {
            private ProgressDialog pDialog;
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
         
                pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                pDialog.setCancelable(true);
               
            }

            @Override
            protected ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

                  ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> categoryList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
               
                SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
              String username = sp.getString("username", "anon");
                    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
                  JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(URL_CATEGORY, "POST",
                            params);
              
                  try {
                    
                      JSONArray categories = json.getJSONArray(TAG_POSTS);
                      for (int i = 0; i < categories.length(); i++) {
                          String id = categories.getJSONObject(i).getString("TAG_ID");
                          String name = categories.getJSONObject(i).getString("TAG_NAME");
                          String pic = categories.getJSONObject(i).getString("TAG_pic");
                          String message = categories.getJSONObject(i).getString("TAG_MESSAGE");
                      
                        HashMap<String, String> queryValuesMap =  new  HashMap<String, String>();
                        
                        queryValuesMap.put("name", name);
                        
                        queryValuesMap.put("message",message);
                        
                        DefaultHttpClient mHttpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                        HttpGet mHttpGet = new HttpGet(pic);
                        HttpResponse mHttpResponse = mHttpClient.execute(mHttpGet);
                        if (mHttpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
                          HttpEntity entity = mHttpResponse.getEntity();
                            if ( entity != null) {
                              // insert to database
                            queryValuesMap.put("image", EntityUtils.toByteArray(entity));
                              
                            }
                        }
             
                            
                            dbTool.insertContact(queryValuesMap);
                         
                      }
                  }catch (Throwable e){
                      e.printStackTrace();
                  }
                  return categoryList;
              }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> result) {
                super.onPostExecute(result);

            
            }
        }
    }
```

the problem is from the

> queryValuesMap.put("image", EntityUtils.toByteArray(entity));

is saying

> The method put(String, String) in the type HashMap<String,String> is not applicable for the arguments (String, byte[])

i don't know if it is the way i arranged it or is there a better way to do it..
go the idea [from this site](https://web.archive.org/web/20200718180158/http://www.tutorialforandroid.com/2009/10/how-to-insert-image-data-to-sqlite.html).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the function `EntityUtils.toByteArray()` is returning exactly that: `byte[]`, but your HashMap is expecting a string.

Try changing this line to

```
queryValuesMap.put("image", new String(EntityUtils.toByteArray(entity)));
```

The constructor `String(byte[])` [will create a new string from your bytes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String(byte[])).